# Xcode giving wrong sum for simple C array

Tags: c, arrays, sum

I have tested my code in both Xcode and an online C Compiler, and for some reason Xcode prints a value of 1606416234 when the correct sum should be 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum_array(int x[], int n);
    int main(void) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int y[4]={1,2,3,4};
    printf("%d\n", sum_array(y, 4));


    return 0;
}

int sum_array(int x[], int n){
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i= 0; i<=n; i++){
        sum+=x[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Why does Xcode give me such a large number?

Answer (score 4):

Your `for` loop goes too far. You need `i < n`, not `<=`. You are reading past the array into unknown memory. That extra value can be filled with anything. In some cases it might be 0 which accidentally gave you the correct result even though the code is wrong.